# React Router not rendering page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, render

I have a component called admin it is a form that will redirect me to another page rendering not working though.

Router main

```js
const globalState = {
  isAuthed: false,
  token: null,
};

export const  AuthContext = React.createContext(globalState);

function App() {

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(globalState)
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={[currentUser, setCurrentUser]}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/admin" component={Admin} />
          <Route exact path="/admin-panel" component={Pannel} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      </AuthContext.Provider>

  )
}

export default App;
```

admin component

```js
const LoginForm = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useContext(AuthContext)

  const login = (state) => {
    const user = document.getElementById('user').value;
    const pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    const request = {
      user,
      pass
    }
    console.log(request)
    fetch('/api/admin', {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(request),
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      if(res.auth){
        valid(5000,"Login Success. Redirecting in 3 second")
        setTimeout(() =>{
          setState({isAuthed: res.auth, token: res.key})
        }, 3000)

      }
      else{
        warn(5000,res.message)
      }
    })
  }

  return(
      <div style={css}>
        <ToastContainer />
        {(state && state.isAuthed)? <Redirect to='/adming-panel'/>: false}
        <h1 style={{color: "teal"}}>Admin Panel</h1>
        <Form id="login-form" size='large' style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}>
          <Segment stacked>
            <Form.Input id="user" fluid icon='user' iconPosition='left' placeholder='E-mail address' />
            <Form.Input
              fluid
              icon='lock'
              iconPosition='left'
              placeholder='Password'
              type='password'
              id="pass"
            />
            <Button onClick={() => login(state)} color='teal' fluid size='large'>
              Login
            </Button>
          </Segment>
        </Form>
      </div>
  )

}


export default LoginForm
```

the new page that I want to render

```js
const Pannel = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useContext(AuthContext)
  return (   
    <div>
      {(!state || !state.isAuthed)? <Redirect to='/adming-panel'/>: false}
      Secret Page
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pannel
```

All the answers that I searched for. Was to put the exact keyword before the path but still, the component won't render only an empty white screen appears and no errors on console or backend console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Route exact path="/admin-panel" component={Pannel} />
```

Spot the key difference

```
<Redirect to='/adming-panel'/>
```

You are welcome.